# apue code chapter 4 umask.c runs abnormal

Tags: c, linux

I run ./umask as the following step:

```
[root filedir]#
[root filedir]#ls
access    bar    cdpwd.c    changemod.c  devrdev.c  filetype.c  ftw8    Makefile  mycd.c  umask.c  unlink.c  zap.c
access.c  cdpwd  changemod  devrdev      filetype   foo         ftw8.c  mycd      umask   unlink   zap
[root filedir]#./umask
[root filedir]#ll foo bar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 7月  23 11:56 bar
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 0 7月  23 11:56 foo
```

Here is the code umask.c

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

#define RWRWRW (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH)

int
main(void)
{
    umask(0);
    if (creat("foo", RWRWRW) < 0)
        err_sys("creat error for foo");
    umask(S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
    if (creat("bar", RWRWRW) < 0)
        err_sys("creat error for bar");
    exit(0);
}
```

as the code above,umask(S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH),why does bar has read access for group and other?

system info :

```
[root filedir]#umask
0022
[root filedir]#cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
[root filedir]#gcc
gcc 4.8.5

Linux MiWiFi-R1CL-srv 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 18 16:35:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/44542/108339 for an explanation of `umask`

Comment: @OlafDietsche my friend run the 4-12 program which modify the file attr,I delete the foo and bar,run ./umask again,it runs as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's embarrassed for me,I make a mistake.
My friend and I share the same virtual machine,he read the book faster than me.He runs 4-12 program,which the code like the following:

```
#include "apue.h"

int
main(void)
{
    struct stat     statbuf;

    /* turn on set-group-ID and turn off group-execute */

    if (stat("foo", &statbuf) < 0)
        err_sys("stat error for foo");
    if (chmod("foo", (statbuf.st_mode & ~S_IXGRP) | S_ISGID) < 0)
        err_sys("chmod error for foo");

    /* set absolute mode to "rw-r--r--" */

    if (chmod("bar", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH) < 0)
        err_sys("chmod error for bar");

    exit(0);
}
```

As for this problem ,I delete the foo and bar,and run ./umask,then everything run well.